# Initializing pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

Can assign a pointer to a value on declaration? Something like this:

```
    int * p = &(1000)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, you can initialize pointers to a value on declaration, however you can't do:

```
int *p = &(1000);
```

& is the **address of** operator and you can't apply that to a constant (although if you could, that would be interesting).  Try using another variable:

```
int foo = 1000;
int *p = &foo;
```

or type-casting:

```
int *p = (int *)(1000); // or reinterpret_cast<>/static_cast<>/etc
```

Comment: Are string constants a special case? Though that would need to be a "const char *"...

Comment: Yes, string literals are special in that they are lvalue expressions, referring to an array object (not a pointer). So you can do 'char const(*p)[3] = &"01";' Not less interesting is initializing a char const* like this: 'char const *p = &"hello there"[0];'

Comment: it doesn't work, i tried, but it showing some garbage type value. **`int *p=(int *)100;`**. then output is something like **`000003E8`**

Comment: 0x000003E8 = 1000 decimal.  If you print 'p' that is what you will see as that is the address you are pointing to.  Read up on pointers.

Comment: About that: I was learning a bit about kernel-space recently and found some code that initializes a pointer as an address (to video RAM). Any ideas as to how that works?

Comment: Regarding other types of casts, I've tested `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast`, and the only ones that work for the one-line initialization exampe `int *p = X_cast<int*>(1000);` are the C-style cast and function-style cast are casts using (type)object or type(object) (which can replace other casts) and `reinterpret_cast`. Any idea why this might be the case? Why aren't we able to perform a `static_cast` here?

Answer (score 13):

What about:

```
// Creates a pointer p to an integer initialized with value 1000.
int * p = new int(1000);
```

Tested and works. ;-)

Comment: But don't forget to delete!

Comment: @GManNickG what is different about this (`new`) when compared to the methods described above?

Answer (score 7):

There are two things not clear in the question to me. Do you want to set the pointer to a specific value (i.e address), or do you want to make the pointer point to some specific variable?

In the latter case, you can just use the address-of operator. The *value* of the pointer is then set to the *address* of `some_int_variable`.

```
int *p = &some_int_variable;
*p = 10; // same as some_int_variable = 10;
```

---

**Note**: What follows is evil changing of the pointer's value manually. If you don't know whether you want to do that, you don't want to do it.

In the former case (i.e setting to some specific, given address), you can't just do

```
int *p = 1000;
```

Since the compiler won't take the int and interpret it as an address. You will have to tell the compiler it should do that explicitly:

```
int *p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(1000);
```

Now, the pointer will reference some integer (hopefully) at address 1000. Note that the result is implementation defined. But nevertheless, that are the semantics and that is the way you tell the compiler about it.

**Update**: The committee fixed the weird behavior of `reinterpret_cast<T*>(0)` that was suggested by a note and for which i provided a workaround before. [See here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#463).

Answer (score 3):

Um. I don't think you can take a non-const address of a constant like that.

but this works:

```
int x = 3;
int *px = &x;
cout << *px; // prints 3
```

or this:

```
const int x = 3;
const int *px = &x;
const int *pfoo = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(47);
```